# Strict mode - type incompatibility when setting value to ngComponentOutlet with lazy-loaded component

Tags: angular, typescript, lazy-loading

I'm trying to lazy-load a component in Angular 11 (strict mode) following [this guide](https://netbasal.com/welcome-to-the-ivy-league-lazy-loading-components-in-angular-v9-e76f0ee2854a).  Strict mode has been a pain because almost no examples/tutorials use it.

This component will load the appropriate header component (eventually).  I'm just trying to lazy-load one for "site A" to start.

**header-loader-component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'header-loader',
  template: `<ng-template [ngComponentOutlet]="headerComponent | async"></ng-template>`,
  styles: []
})
export class HeaderLoaderComponent implements OnInit {

  headerComponent: Promise<Type<SiteAHeaderComponent>>;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.LoadHeaderComponent();
  }

  private LoadHeaderComponent() {
    if (!this.headerComponent) {
      this.headerComponent = import(`../myFolder/siteA-header/siteA-header.component`)
                       .then(({ SiteAHeaderComponent}) => SiteAHeaderComponent);
    }
  }
}
```

With that, I get error:

> Property 'headerComponent' has no initializer and is not definitely
> assigned in the constructor.

Ok, I'm used to that error by now with strict mode, so I change it to:

```
headerComponent: Promise<Type<SiteAHeaderComponent>> | null = null;
```

so it can start null before ngOnInit gets a chance to set it.

Now on `[ngComponentOutlet]` I get:

> Type 'Type | null' is not assignable to type
> 'Type'

How do I set a value for `headerComponent`?

**Edit:**
Just to be sure, I just tried this with Strict temporarily disabled and it works great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `!` symbol with the property when you assign it, like `headerComponent!`.

The `!` symbol with the property name means you are explicitly declaring - "*I know this property has a non-null value*". And in your case if it has a non-null value, then value it has is definitely of type `Type`.

**EDIT :**
Since the property `headerComponent` is of `Promise` type you have to use the `!` symbol enclosing the `async` pipe in the template, like `(headerComponent|async)!`.

Also, I'd recommend to use -

```
headerComponent: Promise<Type<any>> | null = null;
```

Otherwise, you'll not be able to set different type of header component later through the `headerComponent` property.

Comment: I tried `<ng-template [ngComponentOutlet]="headerComponent! | async"></ng-template>` and it still says `Type 'Type<SiteAHeaderComponent> | null' is not assignable to type 'Type<any>'.  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Type<any>'.`  

It's like it simply won't accept null for `ngComponentOutlet`.

Comment: @Roobot Please check the Edit.

Comment: Perfect - thanks! Someone needs to make a guide for strict mode or something.  This is a young project but it's definitely cost me more time than it's saved so far.

Comment: @Roobot IMHO, `strict mode` is not worth using in small, not-so-complex projects because of the time it costs. But you should try it to be familiar with the hassle you have to face if you decide to use it for a large, complex project.